# How to pass a complex java Object to API controller as JSON

Tags: java, spring

I'm stuck since 2 days on this little problem.

I have an object userFilter whose attributes are classic users parameters (name, username, age, etc...).

The type of every attribute is another custom object: RequestParameter<?>

When I try to pass a json to my api controller (method: getAll) with the Spring Boot's @RequestParameter annotation,  the controller it's not filling any UserFilter object with the sent attributes, infact, if i log the requested user, i just get an empty list: [].

Here is the code:

```java
public class Controller<T> {

    @PostConstruct
    static void init() {
        Function<UserPojo, UserModel> toModel = (pojo) -> {
            UserModel model = new UserModel();
            model.setId(pojo.getId());
            model.setName(pojo.getName());
            model.setLastname(pojo.getLastname());
            model.setAge(pojo.getAge());
            model.setAddress(pojo.getAddress());
            model.setUsername(pojo.getUsername());
            model.setEmail(pojo.getEmail());
            model.setPassword(pojo.getPassword());
            model.setGender(pojo.getGender());
            model.setProfilePic(pojo.getProfilePic());
            model.setRegistrationDate(pojo.getRegistrationDate());
            model.setLastLogin(pojo.getLastLogin());
            model.setFriends(pojo.getFriends());
            model.setPosts(pojo.getPosts());
            model.setPublicProfile(pojo.isPublicProfile());
            return model;
        };
        Converter.put(UserPojo.class, UserModel.class, toModel);
    }

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repo;

    @GetMapping("/{Id}")
    public UserModel getUserById(@PathVariable Integer Id) {
        return Converter.convert(repo.getUser(Id), UserModel.class);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{Id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer Id) {
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

    @PutMapping()
    public UserModel updateUser(@RequestBody UserPojo user) {
        return Converter.convert(repo.save(user), UserModel.class);
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public UserModel createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserPojo user) {
        return Converter.convert(repo.createUser(user), UserModel.class);
    }

    @PostMapping("/list")
    public List<UserModel> getAll(@RequestBody UsersFilter param) {
        return Converter.convert(repo.getAll(param.toParam()), UserModel.class);
    }
}
```

```java
public class UsersFilter implements IQueryParamConverter {

    RequestParameter<Integer> id;
    RequestParameter<String> name;
    RequestParameter<String> lastname;
    RequestParameter<Integer> age;
    RequestParameter<String> username;
    RequestParameter<String> email;
    RequestParameter<String> gender;

    public UsersFilter() {
    }

}
```

```java
public class RequestParameter<T> {

    private List<T> value;
    private Operators operator;

    public List<T> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<T> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Operators getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(Operators operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    };

}
```

JSON example:

```json
{
  "id": {
    "value": [
      "1"
    ],
    "op": "EQ"
  }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please insert also the Operators implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the getter and setter for all properties in *UsersFilter* :).
Since it's an Integer *value* array, don't use quotes.
Call the property *operator* with *operator*, not *op* :).
With getters/setters and this json example, worked for me:

```
{
  "id": {
    "value": [
      1
    ],
    "operator": "EQ"
  }
}
```